# Evaluating $\int{e^{-t^{2}}\,dt}$

Tags: integration, summation, euler-mascheroni-constant

Let $f(x) = e^{x}$, which, expressed as a Maclaurin series, is equal to:

$$\sum_{i = 0}^{\infty}{\frac{x^{i}}{i!}}$$

Therefore, $f(-t^{2})$ gives:

$$\sum_{i = 0}^{\infty}{\frac{(-t^{2})^{i}}{i!}} = \sum_{i = 0}^{\infty}{\frac{(-1)^{i}t^{2i}}{i!}}$$

Therefore, $\int{f(-t^{2})\,dt}$ gives:

$$\sum_{i = 0}^{\infty}{\frac{(-1)^{i}}{i!}\int{t^{2i}\,dt}} = \sum_{i = 0}^{\infty}{\frac{(-1)^{i}t^{2i + 1}}{i!(2i + 1)}}$$

Is this correct?

Comment: Yes. This is correct. Sadly the term on the right is not amenable to dissection...

Comment: Ah, thank you very much! @Chanler